# Align Eclipse toolbar icons to left

Tags: eclipse, alignment, customization, toolbar

I've customize my Eclipse toolbar in Java EE perspective, removing some functionalities that I don't use, in order to save space, but Eclipse just remove it and don't align it to left. In Ubuntu, Eclipse remove it and all items are pulled to left, but in Windows a blank space is place where was the removed items were.

[image: blank spaces in red]

Is there any way to force align to left ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. For some reason, no theme was selected in preferences.

Selecting "Classic" and restarting Eclipse fixed.